# Infinite Loop data in array using FOR or FOREACH loop?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

If I can loop this Horizontal array of data no matter how many arrays of data will add, Is there a way to loop that Vertical array of data no matter how many data will be added?

```
// Expect Many arrays of data will be added
$array = [
[1,2,3,4,5],
[101,102,103,104,105],
[10,20,30,40,50],
[210,220,230,240, 250 => ['x','y','z'] ],
[100,200,300,400,500, ['a','b','c'] ],
];

// Loop the array data as added
// Loop Horizontal no matter how many arrays of data's will added

for ( $i=0; $i < count($array) ; $i++) {

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array[$i]);
echo "</pre>";

}
```

```
// How can I loop this array using FOR loop or FOREACH loop ?
// This will loop Vertical Expect that many arrays of data will added or appended on it .

 [210,220,230,240, 250 => ['x','y','z'] ],
 [100,200,300,400,500, ['a','b','c'] ]
```

## Result: Array conversion to string

- Thanks in advance

Comment: So, are you looking for a way to make it recursive? Where it will look through the array, and then if there's an array in the array, it looks through that one too? On and on for as many levels deep as there are?

Comment: Hi @Stevish that's a good term recursive, exactly that is what I am looking for without specifying the array keys, is that feasible?

Comment: I added an answer below. Does that do what you want?

Comment: The function I made below will work for any array no matter how it was generated. I just used the $array you used above as an example. The function is the important part

Comment: Hi, @Stevish Yes, I really like but I am wondering its return is null even the array has value? why?

Comment: Because the function doesn't return anything. If you want it to return something, you'll need to add a return statement to it. What did you want it to return? If you're just echoing something, you can echo it from where I have the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to loop through an array recursively where when you find an array inside an array, you loop through that as well, here's a way to do that:

```
function recursive_loop( $array ) {
    foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
        if ( is_array( $value ) ) {
            recursive_loop( $value );
        } else {
            // Do whatever thing you want to do with each value
        }
    }
}

$array = [
    [1,2,3,4,5],
    [101,102,103,104,105],
    [10,20,30,40,50],
    [210,220,230,240, 250 => ['x','y','z'] ],
    [100,200,300,400,500, ['a','b','c'] ],
];

recursive_loop($array);
```